# Do we really have to change to Object.create?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I have a question for you

As I know, `new` operator works this way

```
function fakeNew(Ctor) {
  var instance = Object.create(Ctor.prototype);
  instance.constructor();
  // I skip the conditional for simplicity
  return instance;
}
```

It all begin when I did a `Object.create` polifill so I could create objects without using `new`.

```
Object.create = function(proto) {
  function F() { }
  F.prototype = proto;
  return new F();
}
```

I started creating a lot of objcts and prototiping them, but as many times then need to initializa its properties I did a `.init()` method to them

```
var base = {
  init: function() {
    EmitterMixin.call(this);
    return this;
  }
};

var obj = Object.create(base).init();
```

But of course, I had to rembember to return `this` always from `.init()` and many times I forget it or worst, I forgot to call `.init()`. So trying to simplify object initialization I wanted to create a global helper to do it: invoke `Object.create`, invoke the initializer function and return this.

```
function create(proto) {
  var child = Object.create(proto);
  child.init();
  return child;
}
```

Then was when I wanted to hit my head against the wall when I realized what I was doing was virtually **what `new` operator does** but a lot slower. And in case the polifill applies I would even use `new` under the hood.

So I ask myself, what benefits throwing `new`? It's [notably quicker](http://jsperf.com/object-create-vs-constructor-vs-object-literal/49) on main browsers and because of javascript nature we usually need to call a initualizer function, something than `new` does from it's begining.

And worst, I've noticed than **I used two different types of objects**, "abstract" and "instances", the bigger difference is than for instances I had to invoke `.init()` while with abstracts it was not necesasary because they will only be used to be prototypes of other objects. And I've already seen this pattern while using `new`:

```
function Foo() { }
Foo.prototype.method = function() { ... };

function Bar() { }
// "abstract" doesnt invoke initializer
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.other = function() { ... };

// "instance", the constructor is called as initializer
var obj = new Bar();
```

Is there really a benefit if we stop seeing `new`? are we sure it's not a higher-level tool than simplifies something we'll have to do anyway?
What pros/cons do you see about `new` and `Object.create`?

Comment: Main [arguments against `new`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful) are "does (lots of) harm when forgotten" and "reminds one too much of class-based inheritance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried both approaches and I don't personally see any problem with the traditional approach using `new`. The main argument for `Object.create` is that it makes the prototypal inheritance more clear - you don't have to understand the intricacy of the `prototype` property on function constructors and how that relates to the actual prototype of the object. But it does require that initialization be a separate step.

My preferred approach is to combine the two approaches, e.g.:

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name || null;
}
Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log('yum');
}

function Cat(name) {
    Animal.call(this, name);
}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

Cat.prototype.meow = function() {
    console.log('meow');
}

var garfield = new Cat('garfield');
garfield.eat();
garfield.meow();
```

`Object.create` is better for inheritance here than `Cat.prototype = new Animal()` for two reasons:

1. If you wanted to require the `name` parameter (throwing an exception if it wasn't passed), you could do so and the inheritance (`Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`) would still work.
2. If you forgot to call the `Cat` constructor from the `Animal` constructor, all of the properties that would have been created by the `Animal` constructor will be undefined instead, allowing you to quickly realize the mistake.

Although this approach (using constructor functions and `new`) is less "purely" prototypal, it's still prototypal inheritance and as long as you understand how to use it correctly it works just fine, and requires a little less typing than the `Object.create` approach.

I wrote some other notes about this in the documentation for my Javascript OO library, [simpleoo](https://github.com/mbrowne/simpleoo.js). (Note: I may be changing the API soon for that library; I'm linking to it mainly because the documentation discusses some of these concepts in more detail.)