# javascript create new object by avoiding new keywords

Tags: javascript, prototype

JavaScript can create a object in many ways.

I try the following code to avoid new keyword to create a new Object of Class A.

My question is that A.prototype.init() here is whether equals new A()? is this good for practice, and why?

```
function A(){
}
A.prototype.init=function(){
    return this;
}

var a = A.prototype.init();
console.log(a);

var a1=new A();
console.log(a1);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkELc/)

Comment: When you call `A.prototype.init` you're not passing a context; it's not the same.

Comment: `A.prototype.init() === A.prototype.init()` but `new A() !== new A()`. They are doing different things.

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you're asking.

Comment: There is no reasonable cause to [avoid the `new` keyword](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful), especially when you have initialisation to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you're doing is returning the `A.prototype` object. You're not really initializing anything, and you're not using the result.

```
console.log(A.prototype === A.prototype.init()); // true
```

So unless you have a particular use in mind, I'd say, no it's not a good practice.

---

Not sure exactly why you want to avoid `new`, but in any case, you can change your constructor so that it can be called with or without `new` and still behave like a constructor.

```
function A() {
    var ths = Object.create(A.prototype);

    ths.foo = "bar";

    return ths;
}
```

Now it won't matter if you use `new`. You're going to get a new object that inherits from `A.prototype` no matter what.

You can still use an `.init()` method, but you might as well just put the logic in the constructor.

---

Furthermore, you can easily create a factory that takes care of that little bit of boilerplate code.

```
function Ctor(fn) {
    return function() {
        var ths = Object.create(fn.prototype);
        fn.apply(ths, arguments);
        return ths;
    };
}
```

So now you'd create your constructor like this:

```
var A = Ctor(function() {
    this.foo = "bar";
});
```

Comment: you are right,although console.log the 'same text', but one of 'this' is prototype and one is object of A. thanks clear my mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `new` by encapsulating your code with the module pattern and returning a function that calls the constructor, in other words:

```
var A = (function ClassA() {

  // Constructor
  function A(prop) {
    this.prop = prop; // instance property
    this._init();
  }

  // Public methods
  A.prototype = {
    _init: function() {

    }
  };

  // Mini factory to create new instances
  return function(prop) {
    return new A(prop); // well, only one `new`
  };
}());
```

Now you can create new instances without `new`:

```
var a = A('foo'); //=> A { prop: "foo", init: function }
```

Comment: Ditch the `ClassA` in this code.  It adds nothing and arguably confuses and isn't very readable.  JSLint will read this as a constructor and throw an error also.  Your variable name should really be the name here.

Comment: It adds meaning. Ditch JSLint for JSHint.

Comment: It uhh... It really doesn't... And no.

Comment: I would even do `init: function init(){}`. Named functions let you trace the stack faster so you can debug without "anonymous function" everywhere.

Comment: To each his own I guess.

Comment: ^^ That's my point xD. Some like JSLint some JSHint, some prefer named function expressions others prefer anonymous. I don't use it everywhere though, I do believe it adds meaning here, you're saying: this is a Class (or a module if you will), not a regular function, given that it returns a factory and not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you catch direct function calls with `instanceof`:

```
function MyConstructor (a, b, c) {
    if (!(this instanceof MyConstructor)) {
        return new MyConstructor(a, b, c);
    }
    // ...
}
```

but there is no good reason to avoid using `new`. `Object.create` and other alternatives can have a significant performance impact.