# "this instanceof Cookies" in Source code of nodejs cookie middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I am trying to understand how the cookie middleware works by looking at the source code. This middleware is going to replace the deprecated cookieParser().
https://github.com/jed/cookies/blob/master/lib/cookies.js

Need some help in explaining the very first sentence:

```
...

function Cookies(request, response, keys) {
  if (!(this instanceof Cookies)) return new Cookies(request, response, keys)

 ...
} ...
```

1. What does "!(this instanceof Cookies)" do? Is it checking the "this" is the function itself?
2. What is the purpose of this code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: trevor's answer is correct, for basic introduction in constructor functions, prototype and the value of `this`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3):

**It makes the `new` keyword optional and these equivalent:**

```
var cookies = new Cookies();

var cookies = Cookies();
```

---

In javascript, an object will be `instanceof` of a function F if the object was constructed by doing `new F()` (or `new G()` where `G` is in the [prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) of `F`).

When you call `new F()`, the function `F` is invoked, and within the function body, `this` refers to a new object that is an instance of `F`. If, however, you simply invoke `F` like `F()`, `this` is set to the global object (`window` in the browser and `global` in node.js).

The line in question is testing to see if the function `Cookies` was invoked with the `new` keyword (like `new Cookies(...)`, in which case `this` will be an object that is an instance of `Cookies` and `this instanceof Cookies` will evaluate to `true`), or whether it was called without (like `Cookies(...)`, in which case `this` will be some object that isn't an instance of `Cookies`). In the second case, the function is called with `new` and returned.

This lets the consumer of the API call `Cookies` with or without the `new` keyword and still get an object that is an instance of `Cookies` back. Without this check, calling `Cookies` without `new` would lead to unexpected results.

### Also see:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/383503/711902

Comment: Thanks for providing this thorough answer!

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to create an instance of Cookies with or without the `new` keyword. `this` refers to the instance. If you call the function without the `new` keyword, `this` will be the global object instead of a new instance.