# Why does a new object constructor overwrite a previous object?

Tags: node.js

I used the following question as a guide for my application's Device object: [Node.js - use of module.exports as a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20534702/node-js-use-of-module-exports-as-a-constructor), but it appears that the first object created is overwritten by a subsequent object constructor.

My object file (MyDevice.js) is as follows:

```
function Device(port) {
  // Load the default device model from JSON file
  var model = require(SomeJSONFile);

  // Update port in the model
  model.port = port;

  // Update object's model    
  this.model = model;
}

Device.prototype.GetPort = function () { 
  return this.model.port;
}

module.exports = Device;// Export
```

In my application (test.js), I do create the objects and print the results:

```
var Device = require("./devices/MyDevice.js");
var device1 = new Device(1);
console.log("device1 port=" + device1.GetPort());
var device2 = new Device(2);
console.log("device2 port=" + device2.GetPort());
console.log("device1 port=" + device1.GetPort());
```

I'm not sure why I get the following output:

```
> node test.js
device1 port=1
device2 port=2
device1 port=2 <--????
```

It appears that the device1 object is overwritten - why would this happen?

---

**Here is the modified code based on @undefined's answer:**

My object file (MyDevice.js):

```
function Device(port) {
  // Load the default device model from JSON file
  var model = require(SomeJSONFile);
  this.model = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model));// 'Unique-ify' model
  this.model.port = port;// Set model parameter(s)
}

Device.prototype.GetPort = function () { 
  return this.model.port;
}

// Export factory function
module.exports = function(port) {
  return new Device(port)
}
```

My application (test.js):

```
var device1 = require("./devices/MyDevice.js")(1);// Call factory function with port=1
console.log("device1 port=" + device1.GetPort());
var device2 = require("./devices/MyDevice.js")(2);// Call factory function with port=2
console.log("device2 port=" + device2.GetPort());
console.log("device1 port=" + device1.GetPort());
```

device2 no longer overwrites device1 - the output is:

```
device1 port=1
device2 port=2
device1 port=1
```

device1 != device2 and because of cloning of the model, device1.model != device2.model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node modules work like singletons. When you require a module, node doesn't create a new object, it returns the same object, so in this case both instances use the same model.

You can test this by using the following conditions:

```
device1.model === device2.model // should return `true`   
device1 === device2 // should return `false`, 2 different instances
```

> How would I get around this?

For having unique models (objects), you have several options:

### Export a factory function

You can define a function that returns an object:

```
module.exports = function() {
   return { ... };
}
```

Now you can require the module and call the exported function.

```
var newModel = require('path/to/module')();
```

### [Clone the object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Another option is cloning the object. The following snippet uses ECMAScript2015's `Object.assign` which creates a shallow copy of the object.

```
var clonedModel = Object.assign({}, model);
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response - I'm thankful that you took the time to respond.

Comment: @HiDefLoLife You are very welcome! I'm glad I could help!