# instances of module functions/classes in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, multiple-instances

I have a project that was started as ES5.1, later I changed it to support ES6 so I was using async-await, let...

now I need to have module/object that is instance-like.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20534942/1183729) post explaining the process, but...

when I do:

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');
var mappings;

function SafeRequestHandler(reqMappings) {

    if (!(this instanceof SafeRequestHandler)) {
        return new SafeRequestHandler((reqMappings));
    }

    mappings = reqMappings;
}

function safeHandleReq(req, res) {
    try {
        let pair = _.find(mappings, {'url': req.url});
        return pair.handler(req, res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

SafeRequestHandler.prototype.safe = safeHandleReq;

module.exports = SafeRequestHandler;
```

but now, each time I do:

```
var handler = require('../util/safeRequestHandler');

let handlerMappings = [
    {
        url: def.party_create,
        handler: partyCreate
    },
    {
        url: def.party_modify,
        handler: partyModify
    },
    {
        url: def.party_get,
        handler: partyGet
    }
];

var handle = new handler(handlerMappings).safe;
```

I get `this.mappings` REPLACED in `SafeRequestHandler` eg. it's NOT an instance.

so I tried ES6 approach defining the handler:

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');

class SafeRequestHandler {

    constructor(reqMappings) {
        this.mappings = reqMappings;
    }

    safeHandleReq(req, res) {
        try {
            let pair = _.find(this.mappings, {'url': req.url});
            return pair.handler(req, res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

}
```

and instantiate it like:

```
let handlerMappings = [
    {
        url: def.party_create,
        handler: partyCreate
    },
    {
        url: def.party_modify,
        handler: partyModify
    },
    {
        url: def.party_get,
        handler: partyGet
    }
];

let handle = new SafeRequestHandler(handlerMappings).safeHandleReq;
```

..but this way I can't even reach out `mappings` in `safeHandleReq(...)`. `this` is undefined, `mappings` is undefined

I think I just don't fully understand basic principles, so can you please correct&explain what is wrong with this two approaches?

Thanks!

Comment: No the ES6 way should work fine.

Comment: well, as I say.. I can not reach 'mappings' everything is undefined

Comment: No, its fine. What error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will lose the context if you store a `method` of a specific class instance into a variable.

```js
// handle doesn't have a pointer to its context (aka, this)
let handle = new SafeRequestHandler(handlerMappings).safeHandleReq;
// so handle() will output cannot read property mappings of undefined
```

Change it to:

```js
const instance = new SafeRequestHandler(handlerMappings);

const handle = (...args) => instance.safeHandleReq(...args);
```

Further info here: [Losing "this" context in JavaScript when passing around members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30486345/losing-this-context-in-javascript-when-passing-around-members#30486415)

Answer (score 0):

Your first code creates a global variable, so theres just *one* value. You might use *this* there too:

```
 let _ = require('lodash');
function SafeRequestHandler(reqMappings) {
  if (!(this instanceof SafeRequestHandler)) {
    return new SafeRequestHandler((reqMappings));
  }
   this.mappings = reqMappings;
}

SafeRequestHandler.prototype.safeHandleReq =  function(req, res) {
    try {
        let pair = _.find(this.mappings, {'url': req.url});
        return pair.handler(req, res);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
module.exports = SafeRequestHandler;
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'mappings' of undefined
..I get with that :/

Comment: @greengold then theres some linter/etc. doing very very bad stuff with your code :/

Comment: trust me, I'm minimal, I dont use such a thing as linter. my only worry is that I'm mixing ES5 with ES6 on 7.7.3... spent hours on this already :(