# Why can't JavaScript constructors create strings or numbers?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have some constructors:

```
function Foo() { }
function FooObject() { return {} }
function FooArray() { return [] }
function FooFunction() { return function () {} }
function FooString() { return '' }
function FooNumber() { return 1337 }
```

And I use them to create some objects:

```
new Foo() // creates Foo instance
new FooObject() // creates object
new FooArray() // creates array
new FooFunction() // creates function
```

Those make sense, but strings and numbers just end up as instances, why?

```
new FooString() // creates FooString instance: WAT
new FooNumber() // creates FooNumber instance: WAT
```

Why is this?

Comment: Just a question: are you using `new` intentionally and consciously? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful This is not a loaded question; I'm just making sure you realize its implications.

Comment: Well... First of all, don't do that. Constructors should be used to create instances of the constructor type, not to return primitives. It doesn't make any sense to return a primitive from a constructor... Constructors return objects.

Comment: `function FooString() { return new String('') }` :)

Comment: @Cuberto that was not the question. I am aware there's no reason to do it. I'm asking why the language performs the way it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the description of the behaviour you are interested in: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-13.2.2

> When the [[Construct]] property for a Function object F is called, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Create a new native ECMAScript object.
> 2. Set the [[Class]] property of Result(1) to "Object".
> 3. Get the value of the prototype property of F.
> 4. If Result(3) is an object, set the [[Prototype]] property of Result(1) to Result(3).
> 5. If Result(3) is not an object, set the [[Prototype]] property of Result(1) to the original Object prototype object as described in
>      15.2.3.1.
> 6. Invoke the [[Call]] property of F, providing Result(1) as the this value and providing the argument list passed into [[Construct]] as the
>      argument values.
> 7. **If Type(Result(6)) is Object then return Result(6).**
> 8. Return Result(1).

Comment: The most important thing here is Step 7. Might be worth highlighting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Strings and numbers in JavaScript are [primitive types](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Variables_and_Types#Primitive_Types), which are immutable. And, because the `new` operator instantiates a new object that is an instance of the given constructor function, you get an object instead of the primitive value. If you called those functions without the `new` operator, you would get the primitive values as you'd expect.

See [the MDN article on the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Comment: "the new operator always instantiates a new object that is an instance of the given constructor function" -- are you sure?