# Why "new function" calls the function?

Tags: javascript, date, new-operator

I was just playing with `Date` object and I observed this

1. new Date() // returns Date object
2. Date() // returns Date in string format

[MDN - Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Description) confirms this

> Note: Note that JavaScript Date objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript Date as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the new operator) will return a string rather than a Date object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript Date objects have no literal syntax.

**Tricky** part is `new Date` returns the same result which `new Date()` returned ?

I tried the same experiment with a normal function,

```
function f() {
  console.log(' I am executed');
}

new f
```

I am surprised to see `I am executed` gets logged. I am trying to find out the reason why f is called when I did not use `execution ()` operator. Can somebody explain me why `new` called the method ?

PS: I don't know what `new f` should have given to me. It was a syntax mistake So I thought it would give me an error. But It does not.

Comment: m59 is right, in javascript function is just another kind of object.

Comment: Parentheses are optional when you use the `new` operator; it's as simple as that.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for clarification. Atleast via this I got to learn something about new :)

Comment: @Pointy would it be reasonable to say that they are optional because you *have* to call the constructor for `new` to work anyway? If not `new f` wouldn't do anything at all because `Function`, wouldn't be invoked and so no "new" function object would be created. Correct?

Comment: @m59 yes, that's right. It doesn't make sense to use `new` if you're *not* calling a function, in other words. I guess one should read a `new` expression as, "I want to construct an object, and here's an expression that evaluates to a reference to the function I want you to call as the constructor." So calling the function is implicit. The slightly weird part is that if you want to call a function to provide the constructor, you have to parenthesize that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `new` will call the constructor of the object you are creating. In the case of a function, the function is both the object and the constructor for that object.

Comment: In case of `new f()` it should call the constructor of what `f()` returns. Isn't it? But even then it calls constructor of f only.

Comment: @blunderboy using `new` automatically invokes the constructor. JavaScript objects are different than what you might be used to. You're probably looking for `Object.create()`. Note that there are also no classes in JavaScript.

Comment: This is just the syntax of JavaScript.  It's a bit weird if you come from a C#, Java or C++ background.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this part of ECMAScript Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) should explain the operation of the `new` operator. In your case, that's 5 in the first section, and 6 on the second section. Basically, JS will call the constructor like a function.

> ## The new Operator
>
> The production `NewExpression : new NewExpression` is evaluated as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating NewExpression.
> 2. Let constructor be GetValue(ref).
> 3. If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 4. If constructor does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on constructor, providing no arguments (that is, an empty list of
>      arguments).
>
> The production `MemberExpression : new MemberExpression Arguments` is
>   evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let ref be the result of evaluating MemberExpression.
> 2. Let constructor be GetValue(ref).
> 3. Let argList be the result of evaluating Arguments, producing an internal list of argument values (11.2.4).
> 4. If Type(constructor) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
> 5. If constructor does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on constructor, providing the list argList as the argument values.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of a "stupid-proof" code.
As you may know, [the new keyword in javascript can be dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful): for example, say you have a classic `Point` constructor:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

This works as expected if you create a point by instantiating the constructor with the `new` keyword. But what if someone forgets to use it?  What is the result of the following code?

```
var myPoint = Point(0, 0);
```

Well, since the constructor itself doesn't return anything (doesn't even have a `return` statement), `myPoint` will be `undefined` instead of a `Point` instance.  And all because of a forgotten `new` keyword.
But have no fear! You can write your code to be stupid-proof:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    // `this` points to the outer scope 
    // if the function is called witouth `new`
    if(!(this instanceof Point))
        return new Point(x, y);

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Although functions such as `Date`, `Array` and so on are built in and we can actually see their source, I strongly believe that they have this safety mechanism by default to prevent newcomers from making trivial stupid errors.