# Using Object.create(), should exemplars have methods attached to their 'prototype' property?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypal-inheritance

I've been reading [Is JavaScript's "new" keyword considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful) and [this Adobe Article on using prototypal inheritance rather than 'new'](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-object-creation.html). The Adobe article has a 'new' example:

```
function Foo() {
    this.name = "foo";
}
Foo.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert("hello from " + this.name);
};
```

...that it replaces with:

```
var foo = {
    name: "foo",
    sayHello: function() {
        alert("hello from " + this.name);
    }
};
```

Here the 'sayHello' method isn't attached to the object's `prototype`. Doesn't this mean 'sayHello' gets unnecessarily duplicated in memory (I know V8 avoids this, but in older JS engines, for example) as it is copied to all objects that inherit from `foo`?

Shouldn't it be:

```
var foo = {
    name: "foo",
    prototype: {
        sayHello: function() {
            alert("hello from " + this.name);
        }
    }
};
```

Or similar?

Comment: Using `new` doesn't mean you are not using prototypal inheritance

Comment: @JuanMendes The argument (as Crock writes it) is that object cloning rather than constructor functions is more consistent with other prototypal languages - see http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html . That said, as others have mentioned, `Object.create()` just calls `new` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is not attached to the prototype because this very object becomes the prototype that is attached to newly created objects with `Object.create`. And you don't need a prototype of the prototype.

Remember that `Object.create` doesn't deep clone objects. Rather, it is equivalent to something like

```
Object.create = function(proto) {

   function F() {}
   F.prototype = proto;
   return new F();

}
```

(actual implementation is more complicated but this short version illustrates the idea)

All newly created objects "inherit" the method from the `foo` which acts as the prototype and there is no duplication here.

Comment: Perhaps it's my understanding of `prototype` that's incorrect. I always read `prototype` (the thing literally called `prototype`) was 'things to be inherited by child objects' rather than `__proto__` which is the real parent object. But I can that's not correct in testing...

Comment: OK read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript which clarified.

Comment: The `prototype` from the constructor function is attached as the `__proto__` to objects created by the constructor function (and objects created by `Object.create` as well, as `Object.create` is a smart wrapper over an anonymous constructor function). Thus, when you call `var f new Foo()`, the `f.__proto__` points to `Foo.prototype`. The latter, `Foo.prototype` can be accessed and changed freely, the former, `f.__proto__` is not intented to be changed directly.

Comment: Btw. I don't see anything "harmfull" in `new`. Actually, it is simpler to define inheritance with `new` and prototypes. On the other hand, prototypal inheritance with `Object.create` is slightly tricker if you need a hierarchy of inheriting objects (like `Worker` iheriting from `Person` and newly created objects inheriting from one of these two).

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't get duplicated if you create another object using that as a protoype. The almost equivalent code using `Object.create` is actually slightly different, you are not using the prototype, you are just creating an object. [To use prototypal inheritance, do the following](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/Dhu8L/). Note that using `new` still sets up the prototype chain so the title of the article you linked to is not very accurate and you are still sharing the properties on a single object.

```
var foo = {
    name: "foo",
    sayHello: function() {
        alert("hello from " + this.name);
    }
};

var extended = Object.create(foo);
var extended2 = Object.create(foo);

extended.name = "first";
extended2.name = "second";
extended.sayHello();  // hello from first
extended2.sayHello(); // hello from second

// Methods are shared, outputs true
console.log(extended.sayHello === extended2.sayHello)

// Now if you delete the property again, it will go up the chain
delete extended.name;
extended.sayHello(); // hello from foo
```

You could also just do

```
var extended = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

It would get duplicated if you create a constructor to get new instances instead of `Object.create` or `new Foo`

```
function createFoo() {
    return {
        name: "foo",
        sayHello: function() {
             alert("hello from " + this.name);
        }
    }
}

var a = createFoo();
var b = createFoo();
 // The function objects are not shared    
alert('Are functions the same? ' + a.sayHello === b.createFoo);
```

They would also not be shared if you use the closure approach to creating objects. Crockford suggests that to create truly private members. I don't use it because it doesn't use the prototype chain and inheritance is tricky to implement without just copying properties.

```
Function Foo() {
    var name = 'foo';
    this.sayHello = function () {
        alert(name);
    };
    this.setName = function (newName) {
        name = newName;
    };
}

var a = new Foo();
var b = new Foo();
console.log(a.sayHello === b.sayHello); // outputs false
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan. I can see that's the case, but still wasn't sure /why/ after reading your answer. Reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript helped.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here, for my own notes and also to help explain to others:

> Q. Using Object.create(), should exemplars have methods attached to their `prototype` property?

**A. No, because Object.create(parentObject) itself sets up the parentObject as the `prototype` of a dynamically-created constructor.**

Also: `prototype` is always a property on constructor Functions - not on regular Objects. Eg:

```
var someArray = [];
someArray.__proto__ === Array.prototype
```

Object.create() dynamically creates constructors, setting the prototype on them to the object in its first argument.