# javascript inheritance and unique instances

Tags: javascript

```
function Shape() {
    this.name = "none"; 
}

function Rect () {        
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
};
```

If all the property of Shape should be available to Rect is it correct to write

```
Rect.prototype = Shape;
```

In this case will each instance of `Rect(i.e. Object.create(Rect))` gets a seperate name from Shape object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the reason to use the 'new' keyword at Derived.prototype = new Base](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Rect.prototype = Shape;` is definitely incorrect. Every instance of `Rect` would have the same properties as the **function** `Shape`. That includes methods that every function has, like `.call` and `.apply`.

But even `Rect.prototype = new Shape;` as suggested in the other answer is not a good solution. While this would add `name` to every instance of `Rect`, every instance would share the same `name` property. But `name` is an **instance specific** property, it does not belong on the prototype. The prototype chain should only hold properties (values) that are supposed to be shared by every instance.

**So, how to do it?**

Add `Shape.prototype` to the prototype chain of `Rect` instances:

```
Rect.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype, {constructor: {value: Rect}});
```

You don't have any custom properties on `Shape.prototype` yet, however, setting this up makes the following work:

```
var r = new Rect();
r instanceof Shape; // true
```

You also have to call the *super constructor* (`Shape`) inside the `Rect` constructor, setting `this` to the new instance:

```
function Rect () {
    Shape.call(this);

    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;
}
```

`Shape.call(this);` is the moment where `name` is assigned to our new `Rect` *instance*.

If you come from Java or another class-oriented OO language, this is basically the same as calling `super();` in the child constructor.

---

All of the above is exactly what the new ES6 `class` syntax does internally.

```
class Rect extends Shape {
  constructor() {
      super();
      // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: With ES6 don't forget that the `Rect` function itself inherits from the `Shape` function as well, i.e. `Object.setPrototypeOf(Rect, Shape)`

Comment: @Bergi: Really? I thought it just copies all static methods. Have to check the spec again...

Comment: I've just looked it up myself to be sure it's still in the draft: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation. In the [harmony proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:maximally_minimal_classes) it was implemented via that fancy literal-inheritance-operator `|>` :-)

Comment: Uh, I didn't get that far, I only read till 2e - you're right :-)

Comment: ehehe :) I still have to get used to the new spec :-/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write the following.

`Rect.prototype = new Shape();`

That would create a new object for `Shape` and then assign it as the prototype for `Rect`. You can't assign a function as a prototype.

Comment: but Doug Crockford advices not to use new operator at all. you mean Rect.prototype = Object.create(Shape);

Comment: Do not listen to Crockford on this, if you need a new instance, use the `new` keyword. Crockford is confused and have for some reason decided that prototypical inheritance is a bad thing, in a  language built around prototypical inheritance

Comment: a) Crockford doesn't say much about this b) You really shouldn't use `new` *here* c) you shouldn't use `Object.create(Shape)` either, it needs to be `Object.create(Shape.prototype)`

Comment: @adeneo I agree with you to not listen to C on the subject of "Classical inheritance" but for the exact reason that he creates an instance of Parent to set prototype part of Child (as you advice). Then claims the Parent constructor can't be re used (ahem: Parent.call...) So Bergi is correct that Object.create is better then creating an instance. More on prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @Bergi - Crockford has been [talking a lot about this](http://nemisj.com/js-without-new-and-this/) lately, he claims we should stop using the `new` keyword all together and use factories that return objects instead, and at one point he claimed that prototypical inheritance is harmful and should never be user. After criticism he changed that to say that `new` should only be used for constructors (which is correct). I probably didn't get the question, I was thinking the point was to do something like -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0kjza73n/**

Comment: @adeneo: I don't know about his latest talks, I only know his website (http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html etc) which is interesting, but partially outdated and definitely non-standard. The article you linked doesn't seem to be written by himself (did I miss something?), I would be glad if you could link a statement from him where he admits that `new` is useful with constructors :-)

Comment: @Bergi - I've at least seen several questions here on SO about this, here's [**one**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascript-s-new-keyword-considered-harmful), I've also attended a talk with Crockford where he proclaimed that prototypical inheritance was dead, and that the `new` keyword was harmful, and I almost choked on my coffee. Here's something he's [**written**](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/jslint_com/conversations/topics/314) at least. I think Ben Gruenbaum had an argument with C about this as well some time ago.