# Instantiating an object in another one

Tags: javascript, oop

Having an object, say `Book` which has a collection of other objects `Page`. So I instantiate pages from raw data passed to `Book`:

```
function Book(data){
    this.pages = [];
    var self = this;
    data.forEach(function(item){
        self.add(item);
    });
}

Book.prototype.add = function(data){
    this.pages.push(new Page(data));
}


function Page(data){
    // some validation code
    this.prop = data.prop;
}
Page.prototype...
```

from lectures on testability I heard that it is a bad practice to instantiate(use `new`) in another object. What is the right way to do the same?

If it is okay - is there any difference if I instantiate a new `Page` in `add()` method or pass to it as an object already(`this.add(new Page(data))`)?

Comment: *I heard that it is a bad practice to instantiate*. What lecture was that? That's a bizarre statement, perhaps you misunderstood it. If you need to create an object, you need to create it, wherever you are.

Comment: Do you want other people to be able to call `Book.prototype.add`? Would you expect them to pass in a constructed `Page` object, or to pass in the data in order to construct one.  Depending on the answer to that, that's your answer - it really depends what interface you want to offer to consumers of your `Book`.

Comment: @torazaburo: I'll assume they meant that `book.add(new Page(…))` is better than `book.add(…)`. Which of course works better for a language that has static typing with interfaces.

Comment: Notice that `this = data` is invalid.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! just in a rush a bit...

Comment: Relying on new to construct objects is considered harmful because if you forget to, it doesn't bind `this` to a new object, but leaves it as possibly the global scope. This results in you throwing lots of garbage into the global scope, possibly messing up a lot of things. However, if you're running in strict mode, this is mostly mitigated as `this` is not automatically bound to the global scope

Comment: @JosephYoung: That sounds like "*relying on function calls is considered harmful because if you forget the arguments, it doesn't work*". [New is *not* harmful](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383402/1048572).

Comment: @bergi I agree, I was just simply stating the possible reason for the lecturer saying it's bad. Especially seeing as it's very easy to mitigate by checking if it was not called using `new`. That being said, the answer goes into the actual reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when you want to write unit tests for you code.

Let's take an actual example. Some times later, your code is this one :

```
function Book(data){
    this.pages = [];
    var self = this;
    data.forEach(function(item){
        self.add(item);
    });
}

Book.prototype.add = function(data){
    var page = new Page(data);

    // Because the page need to know its book        
    page.book = this;

    this.pages.push(page);
}


function Page(data){
    // some validation code
    this.data = data;
}
Page.prototype...
```

Now you want to write an unit test for the `add` method, and you want to check that after you added a new page in your book, the `page.book` is the book. But with a code like that, you can't do it. Becase the page is created inside the method, you can't check anything.

Buf if we rewrite the code like that :

```
Book.prototype.add = function(page){
    page.book = this;
    this.pages.push(page);
}
```

We can now write a unit test :

```
describe('book.add', function() {

    it('should set the current book in the book property of the page', function() {
        var book = new Book(),
            page = new Page();

        book.add(page);

        expect(page.book).toBe(book);
    });

});
```

But, if you do not want to write any unit test like this one, there's no reason to not create the new page inside the method `add`.

Comment: really liked to see the back reference "// Because the page need to know its book "!