# Javascript Prototype Error

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have been trying to create my own Javascript function, and then add methods using `Prototype`

So I create a function:

```
function createObject(){
    this.value = 0;
}
```

And then I create the `Prototype` Method:

```
createObject.prototype.once = function(){
       return this.value+1
};
```

Then I create the instance of the object:

```
var x = createObject();
```

Then, when I try to run `x.once()` I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'once' of undefined
at <anonymous>:1:2
```

And I have no idea why.

Comment: `var x = new createObject();` to instantiate an object instead of just calling the function

Comment: If you intend to use a function as a constructor, it's standard practice to capitalize the function's name, so that you will remember to use the `new` keyword. There's some more good practices associated with the pattern [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/383503/5743988).

Comment: you should think of a better name for the object, because the name `createObject` actually makes the function sound like a function that creates an object - which you would expect to call without the `new` keyword - this doesn't address your problem, but it's probably something to keep in mind

Comment: Constructors are PascalCase (not camelCase) by convention; help people remember to use `new` (ignoring error-checking) by following it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `var x = new createObject()`.

In short, the `new` keyword is what sets up the prototype chain and `this` bindings within the object that your function returns to `x`.

I'd recommend that you take a look at [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You could find this error by placing a breakpoint on the `this.value = 0;` line, and examining `this`; you will find that it is not what you expect.

The most robust solution is to rewrite your constructor to make sure it's being called with `new`, using [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target):

```js
function CreateObject() {
  if (!new.target) throw new TypeError('CreateObject() must be called with new');

  this.value = 0;
}

const object = CreateObject();
```

Linters can help you find this type of error as well. For example, eslint has the [new-cap](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap) option. It will complain if you call a non-capitalized function with `new`, or call a capitalized function without `new`. To take advantage of this, you'll have to follow the convention of capitalizing constructors, as in `CreateObject`.

TypeScript (or ES6 as well) would report an error if you used `class` and tried to instantiate it without `new`:

```
class CreateObject {
  value = 0;

  once() { return this.value = 0; }
}

var x = CreateObject();
```

> Value of type 'typeof CreateObject' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?

Comment: ES6 classes will throw if you try to construct them without `new`, too (re: TypeScript).

Answer (score 1):

When you make instance of class, you have to use `new` keyword, before class name.

```
var x = new createObject();
```

> The new operator creates an instance of a user-defined object type or
>   of one of the built-in object types that has a constructor function.

For more information [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)