# ES6 native Promise from Factory Function

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events

I'm doing a deep dive into ES6 native Promises. Along the way I came across some articles  that quote [Douglas Crockford design choices](https://tsherif.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/constructors-are-bad-for-javascript/) regarding *not* using things like `new`, `Object.create`, `this`, etc. Some people are advocating the use of [Factory Functions](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/common-misconceptions-about-inheritance-in-javascript-d5d9bab29b0a) over constructors. I have also learnt that there is a lot of [heated debate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful) regarding those choices. So to avoid having this question listed as *not constructive*, I'd like to ask this specific question.

How can I create a *factory function* for a Promise without using *new*?

```
// from [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

console.log(promise1);
// expected output: [object Promise]
```

This is also true for using things like building a *new* `Headers()` for a `fetch`.

At some point in the factory function, I'm going to have to write:

```
new Promise();
```

Are DC and the other authors referring to custom objects only, and not builtins? What about all the other [API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) that require the use of *new*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "class-like" function that requires you to call it with `new` keyword you could convert it to a factory function using `Object.create` function. Like this

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayHi = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
}

const makePerson = (name) => {
  const person = Object.create(Person.prototype);
 
  Person.call(person, name);
  
  return person;
}

makePerson('Joe').sayHi()
```

But this wont work with Promise because (from spec)

> Promise is not intended to be called as a function and will throw an
>   exception when called in that manner.

```js
const makePromise = (executor) => {
  const promise = Object.create(Promise.prototype);
  
  Promise.call(promise, executor); //this line throws
  
  return promise;
}

try {
  makePromise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Hi!')).then(console.log)
} catch(e) {
  console.error('Crashed due to ', e.message)
}
```

Again **but** there is an **ultimate** factory that comes with Reflect API [`Reflect.construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/construct). So if you want to avoid using `new` at all costs you could do it like this

```js
const makePromise = (executor) => {
  return Reflect.construct(Promise, [executor], Promise)
}

makePromise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Hi!'))
  .then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway in some place you need to call the `new` keyword. You have already done the 99%.

```
function promiseFactory(bodyFunc) {
  return new Promise(bodyFunc);
}
```

And use this like

```
const promise = promiseFactory((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo'));
```

Example

```js
function promiseFactory(bodyFunc) {
   return new Promise(bodyFunc);
}

const promise1 = promiseFactory((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo'));
const promise2 = promiseFactory((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'boo'));

promise1.then(r => console.log(r));
promise2.then(r => console.log(r));
```

If you want to use already resolved or rejected Promise, you can use [**Promise.resolve**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) and [**Promise.reject**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) respectively.