# Why need to new a promise when reading streams?

Tags: node.js

ok i saw this example of reading a stream and returning a promise using new Promise.

```
function readStream(stream, encoding = "utf8") {
    
    stream.setEncoding(encoding);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = "";
        
        stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
        stream.on("end", () => resolve(data));
        stream.on("error", error => reject(error));
    });
}

const text = await readStream(process.stdin);
```

My question is why "new Promise" ? can i do it in the 2nd version like

```
function readStream(stream, encoding = "utf8") {
    
    stream.setEncoding(encoding);

        let data = "";
        
        stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
        stream.on("end", () => Promise.resolve(data));
        stream.on("error", error => Promise.reject(error));

}

const text = await readStream(process.stdin);
```

Haven't tried it yet, but basically want to avoid the new keyword.

---

some updates on the 2nd version, since async functions always return a Promise.

A function/method will return a Promise under the following circumstances:

You explicitly created and returned a Promise from it's body.
You returned a Promise that exists outside the method.
You marked it as async.

```
const readStream = async (stream, encoding = "utf8") => {
    
    stream.setEncoding(encoding);

        let data = "";
        
        stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
        stream.on("end", () => Promise.resolve(data));
        stream.on("error", error => Promise.reject(error));
}

const text = await readStream(process.stdin);
```

How's this 3rd version ?

Comment: No, second version can't work, because `readStream` no longer returns a promise. The  `Promise.resolve` values are going nowhere.

Comment: Out of curiosity.. what's wrong with using the *new*-keyword? :)

Comment: @eol well i want to stay with functional style, don't want to use class/new if possible

Comment: Maybe this is interesting for you then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516338/3761628

Comment: Things like error extensions and promises are not related to oop even if you have to use class/new. It is a way to have more readable code

Answer (score 4):

If you want `readStream` to return a promise, you'll have to ... return a promise for `readStream` (returning a promise in some callback is not doing that).

What the first code is doing, is *promisifying* the `stream` API. And that's exactly how it should be done.

The second version of the code is based on a misunderstanding: it seems to hope that returning a promise in the callback passed to the `stream.on` method, will somehow make `readStream` return that promise. But when the `on` callback is called, `readStream` has already returned. Since `readStream` has no `return` statement, it already returned `undefined` and not a promise.

As a side note, when the stream API calls the callback you passed to the `on` method, it does not even look at the returned value -- that is ignored.

The third version is an `async` function, so it now is guaranteed the function will return a promise. But as the function still does not execute a `return` statement, that promise is immediately resolved with value `undefined`. Again, the returned values in the callbacks are unrelated to the promise that the async function has already returned.

### `new` keyword

If you want to avoid the `new` keyword, then realise that anything that can be done *with* promises can also be done *without* them. In the end promises are "only" a *convenience*.

For instance, you could do:

```
function readStream(stream, success, failure, encoding="utf8") {
    let data = "";
    stream.setEncoding(encoding);
    stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
    stream.on("end", () => success(data));
    stream.on("error", failure);
}

function processText(text) {
    // ... do something with text 
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    // ... do something with the error
}

readStream(process.stdin, processText, errorHandler);
```

In typical Node style you would pass one callback, for both purposes, as last argument:

```
function readStream(stream, encoding="utf8", callback) {
    let data = "";
    stream.setEncoding(encoding);
    stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
    stream.on("end", () => callback?.(null, data));
    stream.on("error", err => callback?.(err, null));
}

function processText(err, text) {
    if (err) {
        // do something with err
        return;
    }
    // ... do something with text 
}

readStream(process.stdin, "utf8", processText);
```

And then you could use the `util` package to turn that into a promise-returning function:

```
const util = require('util');

const readStream = util.promisify(function (stream, encoding="utf8", callback) {
    let data = "";
    stream.setEncoding(encoding);
    stream.on("data", chunk => data += chunk);
    stream.on("end", () => callback?.(null, data));
    stream.on("error", err => callback?.(err, null));
});

(async () => {

    try {
        const text = await readStream(stream, "utf8");
        // do something with text
    } catch(err) {
        // do something with err
    }

})();
```

Of course, under the hood the `promisfy` function performs `new Promise` and we're back to where we started.

Comment: see my 3rd version

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: I love your solution without new and promise, clean and easy to understand !

Comment: Last one is good, but callbacks are not node style. Node style callbacks are always the last parameter of a function and have two parameters, the first is error and the second is data `function(error, data)`, like in fs.readFile. If error ocurred, callback will be called as `callback(error, null)`, on success `callback(null, data)`.

Comment: @Aziz, true. I have extended the answer to cover that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct and return a Promise so that the consumer of the function has something to hook into the asynchronous action being performed. (Another option would be to define the function to also take a callback as an argument.)

If you try to do it the way you're doing with the second snippet, `readStream` will not return anything, so `await readStream(process.stdin);` will resolve immediately, and it'll resolve to `undefined`.

Doing

```
stream.on("end", () => Promise.resolve(data));
```

and

```
stream.on("error", error => Promise.reject(error));
```

constructs new Promises *at that point in the code*, but you need the consumer of the function to have access to the Promise that resolves (or rejects) - and so you must have `return new Promise` at the top level of the function.

Comment: see my 3rd version

Comment: It's not any different, making a function `async` doesn't mean that any Promises created inside it are connected with the Promise the function returns. (A function can have multiple promises inside it, after all.) You need a `return`.

Comment: just need to add "return" keyword before Promise.resolve(data), Promise.reject(error), right ?

Comment: No, you're already returning them to the caller of the `.on` callback with the arrow functions' implicit return - but that doesn't do you any good because they need to be returned from `readStream`, which is a higher level up. You need to return from the top level of `readStream` for `readStream` to return a value.