# Javascript push and loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, push

I currently have this array: var arr = []
How do I push multiple "hello" strings into the array using a for loop?
I tried

```
var newArray = arr.push("hello")10;
```

Comment: take a look at array.fill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: `var arr =  new Array(10).fill("hello")`

Answer (score 0):

try new Array `forEach` or simple for-loop should work.

```js
var arr = [];

// method 1
new Array(5).fill(0).forEach(() => arr.push("hello"));

// alternate method
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  arr.push("world");
}

console.log(arr);

// Updating based on suggesion @mplungjan, quick way without loop.
var arr2 = Array(10).fill("hello");
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: `var arr =  new Array(10).fill("hello")`

Comment: Oh right, Thanks @mplungjan. Just realising I think further short way is `var arr = Array(10).fill("hello")`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383402/is-javascripts-new-keyword-considered-harmful