# How to attach an event listener to a javascript var

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-events

I am a somewhat green programmer, and quite new to javascript/jquery, but I thought I understood javascript events. Apparently not. I am not able to get event listeners to work as I'd like.

Given javascript:

```
var Thing = {
    //stuff
    update: function() {
        $.event.trigger({type:'stateUpdate', more:stuff});
    }
};

var Room = {
    //more stuff
    updateHandler: function (e) {
        //handle event here
    }
};
```

If I do jquery:

```
$(document).on('stateUpdate', $Room.updateHandler);
```

then it works fine, but I can't do either

```
$(Room).on('stateUpdate', $Room.updateHandler);
```

or

```
Room.addEventListerner('stateUpdate', $Room.updateHandler);
```

The first does nothing, the second gives .addEventListerner is not a function error.

I've googled for hours and can't figure it out. I found something that said .addEventListener only works on objects that implement EventListener, something about handleEvent, and something about functions automatically implementing EventListener. Nothing on how to make an object implement it. Is there no way to add listeners to javascript objects that aren't functions? Am I going to have to create an event handler object, or use 'document' or 'window' and have it call handlers? That seems really ugly.

Should the objects be functions in the first place? Would that work? It seems the current opinion is that making everything functions is just trying to make javascript into something it isn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add an eventListener to an Object in javascript which will fire when object is manipulated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903226/how-to-add-an-eventlistener-to-an-object-in-javascript-which-will-fire-when-obje)

Comment: Event listeners are only for DOM elements, not arbitrary Javascript objects. See the linked question for more details.

Comment: I imagine this isn't unheard of behavior. Is there a "proper" way to go about doing this beside listeners? (preferably that promotes modularity, i.e. more 'rooms' added later with minimal or no 'thing' editing) Invisible DOM intermediaries is all I can think of besides direct calls in the 'thing' update function, are such DOM objects bad practice?

Comment: The normal way to do this is with function and method calling. I don't see what you gain by expressing it as events, other than consistency with the way DOM events are handled.

Comment: Oh duh. You mean something like having the 'rooms' register a callback with 'thing' for updates, right? I think that would solve everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no way to add a event listener to the plain object, as it is not placed inside DOM. Events are firing inside DOM, and bubbling so your event listener for custom object won't receive it.

There is a http://www.bobjs.com/ framework that can help you implement custom events.

Answer (score 0):

In response to @Barmar (sort of) I believe I worked this out. Confirmation on if this is a a good alternative or not would be nice, though. Basically, I have to do a subscriber thing, right? Almost event/listener, but not quite.

```
var thing = {
    callbacks: {},
    regCallback: function (key, which) {
        callbacks[key] = which;
    },
    remCallback: function (key) {
        callbacks[key].delete;
    }
    update: function(e) {
        for(var i = 0, len = callbacks.length; i < len;i++){
            callbacks[i](e);
        };
    }
};

var Room = {
    updateHandler: function () {
        //handle stuff
    },
    subscribe: function (which, callback) {
        which.regCallback('room', callback);
    }
    unsub: function (which) {
        which.remCallback('room');
    }
};

//wherever/whenever I need to get updates something like
Room.subscribe(thing, Room.updateHandler);
//unsub
Room.unsub(thing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Second error is caused by typo: `addEventListerner` has extra `r` in it.