# What happens to Click events on <object>

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have created a `div`, and within that `div`, I referenced a SVG image via `object` (I want to manipulate that SVG image later on...).

```html
<div id="click-me">
   some needless Text
   <object data="some.svg" />
</div>
```

And then I register some event handlers on the `click` event:

```js
document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log("Click handled");
});
```

Now the following happens: The registered click handler do work perfectly on the text, but do now work on the SVG image.

Am I doing something in a wrong way?
What do I oversee?

Here is the Plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/TZm7MxSfiwswz01HCwA9?p=info

Comment: Does your svg has height and weight?

Comment: Yes, it does: `width="500pt"` and `height="600pt"` in this example.

Comment: Clicks on an embedded svg aren't registered unless you include them in the svg itself. Although with jQuery, you might be able to get it to work with `.contents()`.

Comment: If you want the whole SVG drawing to be a single object that you click anywhere on, include it as an image rather than an object.

Comment: Problem with including it as an image is, that I cannot manipulate it via javascript afterword.

Comment: Tested `.contents()` but there is no jQuery workaround.

Comment: Actually, if you click on the TOP LEFT corner of the SVG image the click will be registered. I mean this area: http://prntscr.com/6nm7qg

Comment: That's not part of the object though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835768/addeventlistener-on-custom-object Perhaps this might be useful.

Comment: I think the plunkr is getting in the way with cross-site errors (or at least for me). Here is an example using Snap, see if this is what you mean. No reason if that works for you, it couldn't be done with just js. http://svg.dabbles.info/snapobject.html

Comment: That's a huge plugin for a simple image to be honest. My idea would be to put the whole svg inline (`<svg> ... </svg>`). It will then be clickable and you can access it with JavaScript. If it's considered to be crowding the page source that way you could dynamically add/load it.

Answer (score 2):

As some workaround for this, I've found the CSS rule `object { pointer-events: none; }` to be working.

But it can be only a workaround, if you don't care which item of `object` you have clicked on, i.e. you care only about whether it's clicked on.

Comment: This seems to work quite well apart from limited (but still okay) browser support.